# Why in order to be a binary operation on $S$, each element of $S$ has to appear 'once and only once' in each row and column in Cayley Table?

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

I was reading about Composition table or Cayley Table; one of the points my book presents is that

> If all the entries of the table are elements of set $S$ and **each element of $S$ appears *once and only once* in each row and column**, then the operation is a binary operation.

The first row of the table contains elements $a_1*a_1,\,a_1*a_2,\,a_1*a_3,\,\cdots$

Now, according to the statement, in order for $*$ to be a binary operation, $a_1*a_1\ne \,a_1*a_2\ne \,a_1*a_3\ne \,\cdots\,$ is it so?

If yes, I'm not getting the reason behind it. What would be the problem if $a_1*a_1= \,a_1*a_2 = \,a_1*a_3\;?$

Can anyone please explain to me what the bold statement means?

Comment: Suppose $a_1*a_2 = a_1*a_3 = b$. What would $a_1^{-1}*b$ be?

Comment: This follows from uniqueness of inverses.

Comment: @Rahul: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Good question.  I'm presuming the book is considering this as a criterion of definition.  It's true for groups.  I don't think it *is* usually considered a property of binary operations.  Actually I'm confused by this.  The usual definition is simply two ordered elements result in an element of the set.  I was under the impression that a constant operation would be a binary operation if the constant was a member of the set.

Comment: @fleablood: Yes, that is what I'm saying; the operation must give an element that belongs to $S$, that's it. I didn't know of the bold fact earlier,

Comment: But your interpretation of what they statement means is correct.

Comment: Math 100,  that's assuming the table is for a group.  A binary operation on a set need not, have an identity, an inverse, need not be associative, need not have *any* significance at all.  However, if the book is "group centric" it can simply consider only group type operations are significant.

Comment: If the elements in the table *weren't* elements of the set or if some cells in the tables didn't have values then it wouldn't be a binary operation.  The condition that each element appears exactly once in a row *isn't* a requirement.  However if the set and operation defines a group, it would be a condition as a result of group properties.  Out of context the statement is odd, but in context it maybe is clear that they are determining the operation to be binary as a precurser to declaring it a group.

Comment: @Math1000: Check fleablood's comments above.

Answer (score 0):

On my third reading, I realize that the statement states *IF all elements appear exactly once THEN* it is a binary operation.  The converse (if binary than every element appears once) is *NOT* actually stated and shouldn't be implied.

As stated this is actually a trivial statement.  If every element of the set appears exactly once, then all possible pairs have a result and the only results are members of the set.  So it's binary.  It'd also be binary if every element *didn't* appear exactly once.

Notice it's an *IF*, not an *IF AND ONLY IF*. Nor is it a definition.

All it's saying is if it's a precise and specific type of binary operation, then it is a binary operation.  This is a bit like saying, if someone is a New York male resident between 20 and 30 years old with a social security number, than he is a human being.  ... well, he *is*!